# Rewriting $x^3-3xy^2+2xy+i(-y^3+3x^2y-x^2+y^2 )$ in terms of $z$, with $z=x+yi$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

How do I write $f=u+iv$
with:
$u=x^3-3xy^2+2xy$ and 
$v=-y^3+3x^2y-x^2+y^2  $
in terms of $z$ with $z=x+yi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of the binomial theorem? It tells us that (for example) $$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$ and $$(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^3+b^3.$$ See if you can use those to do the trick, bearing in mind that $i^2=-1$.

Comment: Yes this works indeed. But I dislike the 'guessing' of $a$ and $b$ a bit :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the substitution
$$
x=\frac{1}{2}(z+\overline{z}), y=\frac{1}{2i}(z-\overline{z}).
$$
After simplification you will get $z^3-i z^2$.

Comment: Is there some shortcut you used? Formulas will otherwise get very long with your method.

Comment: No, it  is universal method. I used Maple for simplification.